# set html select option with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list in a select. After selecting an option i do a check and occasionally i want to change the selected to index 0 (first option, value=""). How do i set the select to that option with jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you are looking for:

```
$('select > option')[0].selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

$('select > option')[0].attr('selected','selected') should work i think

Answer (score 0):

select > option = get descendant of select
:eq(0) means get the first (index=0)
and then set attribute

```
$("select > option:eq(0)").attr("selected","selected")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it wasn't asked for, but I used this to select the first value in all my DropDownLists

```
$("option:first-child").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [extension method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/) that will do this so you can simplify your inline syntax

```js
$.fn.extend({
    deselect: function() {
        this.filter("select").each(function() { 
            $("option", this)[0].selected = true;
        });
    }
});
```

Then, you can call it like this:

```js
$("#selector").deselect();
```

Here's a demo:

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/FsQMD/)